# Eliminating a direction from a vector

Tags: math, vector, geometry, 2d, game-physics

I'm programming a really simple 2D collision response algorithm (thankfully), but even the really simple geometry concepts have been baffling me.  Been studying!  But...

In this case, it's vectors:

If an object hits a piece of geometry, I want to completely eliminate that object's momentum in the direction parallel to the normal of the geometry's wall.  There's no friction or bounce involved luckily, but even still I'm not sure how to find a vector that will completely negate that momentum along the normal.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you familiar with basic vector operations (addition, subtraction, scalar multiplication, dot product)?

Comment: @Beta: Yeah!  I made a small vector class, which can do addition, subtraction, scalar multiply, dot/cross product, and that good stuff

Comment: Calculate the motion normal to the plane, then subtract that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Calculate the dot product of the geometry wall normal with the velocity vector of the object. The result equals the velocity component in the direction of the wall normal. Subtract the wall normal multiplied by this result from the velocity vector to remove all velocity in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you look for the reflection formula, there is a term there that subtracts twice the velocity in the direction of the geometry normal. Change that to 1 times and it will stop instead of bouncing. Sorry, no time for formulas ;-)

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Comment: OP did not want bounce/reflection.  Also formula is formatted poorly (unsymmetrical).

Comment: @Tom Sorry, I'm just a poor physicist. I'm sure you can understand the requirement better than me.